# What is the word for an animal species which only eats one type of food?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for an animal that eats only one type of food? The giant panda, for example, only eats bamboo; koalas only eat eucalyptus leaves. "Monovore" would be ideal, but I don't believe that word exists (at least, it's not in the OED). So an obvious sample sentence would be: "The giant panda is a/an ***** as it only eats bamboo".

Comment: [Lotsofwords.com](https://lotsofwords.com/%2Avore) provides pretty comprehensive-looking lists for words ending -_wxyz_ say. I've had fun looking through the words (and, as they admit, candidate words) ending in -_vore_ on the relevant 'page', but have found no term with the meaning you desire. ... 'Univore' has been used, albeit 'metaphorically' [[Glosbe.com](https://glosbe.com/en/en/univore) // [ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304422X04000555)].

Comment: An animal that eats just one kind of food is pre-extinct...

Comment: They are all pre-exstinct, but some co-evolve

Comment: It usually works better if you don't try to mix Latin with Greek, and stick to one of them (either one).

Comment: @RonJohn an egg contains everything necessary to grow a hatchling. Do egg-eating snakes eat anything except eggs? The same comment may apply to seeds, but AFAIK all birds need to feed their chicks on insects even if they are seed-eating herbivores as adults. Non-birds?

Comment: @nigel222 if that snake only eats one species' eggs, or the bird only eats one kind of bug or plant's seeds that's a problem for long term survival in a changing environment.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Monophagous**

> : feeding on or utilizing a single kind of food
>   especially : feeding on a single kind of plant or animal

From Merrim Webster Online :[monophagous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monophagous)

The noun is *monophage*.

Comment: While the answer is correct for the question as it is expressed in the title, the question is wrong/misleading in its detail. The koala does not, from a scientific perspective, “eat one type of food”. It eats a range of quite different eucalypts species (including monkeygum, various stringybarks, woollybut, red iron bark and silver-top ash), and must do so to stay healthy. There is no denying it is a very fussy specialised eater, but most scientists would call it *oligophagous* (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oligophagous).

Comment: The panda might also be called an oligophage in some circumstances - where two bamboo species are available it will eat both to secure a wider range of nutrients. The word *monophagous* is most often applied to invertebrates - for example butterfly species that that will only lay their eggs on, and eat, one particular plant species.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Yes, and I happen to be an amateur entomologist a long way from Oz. I think your comment would best be a separate answer, or I can edit my answer later when I get home.

Comment: Great. You are welcome to just incorporate my comments into your answer. It is after all fundamentally correct. By the way, this is a reference for the diet of koalas in a particular location (they eat different eucalypts in different locations around the country): https://www.aph.gov.au/DocumentStore.ashx?id=b0014f33-c389-4128-aeec-9c0c798ecc2a

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the less common but more poetic **monovore**.

Comment: You should include a dictionary source & definition for your chosen word.

Comment: This was already mentioned in the OP as a potentially good word that however might not exist.

Comment: Better to use the existing monophage which doesn't mix Latin and Greek the way 'monovore' would.

Comment: @killingtime If we all abided by that constraint, we'd never get any new words.